# Extract a certain element from URL using regular expressions

Tags: nsregularexpression, google-bigquery

I need to extract the first element ("adidas-originals") after "designer" in the following URL using regular expressions.

```
xxx/en-ca/men/designers/adidas-originals/shorts
```

This needs to be done in Google Big Query API (standard SQL). To this end, I have tried several ways to get the desired valued without any success. Below is the best solution that I have found so far which obviously is not the right one as it returns "/adidas-originals/shorts".

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(hits.page.pagePath, r'designers([^\n]*)')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `[^\n]*` matches 0 or more chars other than a newline, LF, so no wonder it matches too much.

You need a pattern to match up to the next `/`, so you may use

```
designers/([^/]+)
```

Or a more precise:

```
(?:^|/)designers/([^/]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6H201j/1)

**Details**

- `(?:^|/)` - either start of a string or `/` (you may just use `/` if `designers` is always preceded with `/`)
- `designers/` a `designers/` substring
- `([^/]+)` - Capturing group 1 (just what will be returned with the `REGEXP_EXTRACT` function): one or more chars other than `/`.

Comment: It's perfect. Thanks!